# How to compute this double integral in r?

Tags: r

I'm wanting to compute an integral of the following density function :

[image]

Using the packages "rmutil" and "psych" in R , i tried :

```
X=c(8,1,2,3)

Y=c(5,2,4,6)

correlation=cov(X,Y)/(SD(X)*SD(Y))

bvtnorm <- function(x, y, mu_x = mean(X), mu_y = mean(Y), sigma_x = SD(X), sigma_y = SD(Y), rho = correlation) {
  force(x)
  force(y)
  function(x, y) 
    1 / (2 * pi * sigma_x * sigma_y * sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2)) * 
    exp(- 1 / (2 * (1 - rho ^ 2)) * ((x - mu_x) / sigma_x) ^ 2 + 
          ((y - mu_y) / sigma_y) ^ 2 - 2 * rho * (x - mu_x) * (y - mu_y) / 
          (sigma_x * sigma_y))
}

f2 <- bvtnorm(x, y)

print("sum_double_integral :")

integral_1=int2(f2, a=c(-Inf,-Inf), b=c(Inf,Inf)) # should normaly give 1 

print(integral_1)  # gives Nan
```

**The problem :**

This integral should give 1 , but it gives Nan ??
I don't know how can i fix the problem , i tried to force() x and y variables without success.

Comment: I know about `sd` but what is `SD`? R is case sensitive.

Comment: @John Coleman , standard deviation in "psych" package is written in upper-case  ( SD ) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a pair of parentheses. The corrected code looks like:

```
library(rmutil)
X=c(8,1,2,3)

Y=c(5,2,4,6)

correlation=cor(X,Y)

bvtnorm <- function(x, y, mu_x = mean(X), mu_y = mean(Y), sigma_x = sd(X), sigma_y = sd(Y), rho = correlation) {

  function(x, y) 
    1 / (2 * pi * sigma_x * sigma_y * sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2)) * 
    exp(- 1 / (2 * (1 - rho ^ 2)) * (((x - mu_x) / sigma_x) ^ 2 + 
          ((y - mu_y) / sigma_y) ^ 2 - 2 * rho * (x - mu_x) * (y - mu_y) / 
          (sigma_x * sigma_y)))
}

f2 <- bvtnorm(x, y)

print("sum_double_integral :")

integral_1=int2(f2, a=c(-Inf,-Inf), b=c(Inf,Inf)) # should normaly give 1 

print(integral_1)  # prints 1.000047
```

This was hard to spot. From a debugging point of view, I found it helpful to first integrate over a finite domain. Trying it with things like first [-1,1] and then [-2,2] (on both axes) showed that the integrals were blowing up rather than converging. After that, I looked at the grouping even more carefully.

I also cleaned up the code a bit. I dropped `SD` in favor of `sd` since I don't see the motivation in importing the package `psych` just to make the code less readable (less flippantly, dropping `psych` from the question makes it easier for others to reproduce. There is no good reason to include a package which isn't be used in any essential way). I also dropped the `force()` which was doing nothing and used the built-in function `cor` for calculating the correlation.

Comment: thank you a lot M. for your precious remarks and help !